# JavaFX setCellFactory doesn't set my item

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I have got a problem with my cellFactory.
I want that if a Date is set to my object inside a FX TableView, that the updateItem method checks if it is a valid date. If not the cell should be colored red.

```
    _availableCol.setCellFactory(column -> {
        return new TableCell<SimpleReservationUnit, LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(date, empty);
                if (empty || date == null) {
                    setText(null);
                }else {
                    if (date.compareTo(_newDeparture.getValue()) < 0) {
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
                    }else{
                        setStyle("");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

The coloring works, but the LocalDate is never set to the cell. As far as I understand this should happen in the super() call.
A CellValueFactory is implemeted for this column:

```
_availableCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Available"));
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: "As far as i understand this shoul happen in the `super()` call.". No: `TableCell.updateItem(...)` does not set any text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the text of the node. You do clear it when you detect it is empty, but you don't set it when it is not. You also forget to clear the style if the cell is empty.

```
if (empty || date == null) {
  setText(null);
  setStyle(""); // can this be null?           
} else {
  LocalDate departureDate = _newDeparture.getValue();
  String text = departureDate.toString();  // or format it for user locale
  setText(text);
  String style = date.isBefore(departureDate) ? "-fx-background-color: red" : "";
  setStyle(style);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I thought that the line "setItem(item);" in the super method will set the item and will be adequate for my needs.I didn't realize that I also have to use the setText. Thanks alot!